# How to Index my website?

Tags: seo

How can i Index my website? I have tried all things which google suggesting me still my website is not getting Indexed from last 30 Days?

Comment: Welcome to Pro Webmasters. We get this question quite a lot, so rather than having multiples of the same question, we mark it as a duplicate of an earlier one to focus answers in the same place. However, you've gotten a nice answer below too.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you have tried. It really is as simple as doing nothing. Google will find your site and if it can crawl the site, it will index it.

The best thing you can do is to create a Google Webmaster Tools account for the site. This will let Google know your site exists. If you have a sitemap, you can submit it. Smaller sites do not need one, but it does not hurt to submit one anyway. Google will read the sitemap and begin to index the site sometime after that though it is not guaranteed that Google will use the sitemap to index your site. Please understand that Google Webmaster Tools shows stats 2 days behind. As well, you may also want to add Google Analytics to your site. Another option is adding a Google search engine option (I forget the exact name) to your site. Google usually indexes a site beginning within just a few days until done.

Now on the flip-side, just because your site is indexed, does not mean that searches for your keywords will yield much result. Most new sites do not perform well for quite a while. Be that as it may, you can always do a site:mydomainname.com search in Google to see how many pages are indexed. Do not panic if this number fluctuates up and down. This is normal.

All and all, search engines are notoriously slow. Very slow in fact! Back links are often required and so you should be carefully creating back links for your site. Do not over do it though. I suggest reading as much as you can on creating back links. Read current advice because back link strategies have changed. Just know that back links from forums, comment sections, and some blogs carry little weight and some or too many can spell trouble.

That should get you started. Do these things and it will all work out okay. Just remember that you will need to have patience. A lot of patience.